# Getting data from user in java

Tags: java

I tried to test 2 ways of getting data from user. I faced 2 errors, as I attached.
**First error:**
[image]
**Second error:**
 [image]
I have second error (`Obeject is never closed`) with every object which I create from Scanner class!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InputStreamReaderClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Method 1:
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
    System.out.println("Type text 1: ");
    String text = buffer.readLine();



    //Method 2:
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Type text 2: ");
    String text2 = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 you have to fix. You have to handle the error. The issue with the second method is a warning, and the program will still run without the fix, but it is a good idea to get in the habit of closing objects you're not using.

Method 1 needs to be surrounded by a `try/catch` statement, or you need to throw and exception:

```
try{
    // Method 1:
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
    System.out.println("Type text 1: ");
    String line = buffer.readLine();
}catch(Exception e){
  //handle error
 }
```

This is because `BufferedReader.readLine()` throws an exception, and you need to handle it. You can get more info from the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Method 2, you need to close the scanner object:

```
//Method 2:
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
String line2 = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Type text 2: ");
scanner.close();
```

You don't necessarily have to close the scanner, but it is a good practice.

Comment: **Method** 1: why we cannot use it without "**try/catch**"? **Method 2**: actually I know about "**close.()**"; I dont know the reason. since, I cannot see it in other programs on the net, why I should put it in my code?

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, but when I run the program, nothing happens.

Comment: @Hengameh, not really sure what you are trying to do. The program you have will simply ask a user to input text, but you don't do anything. So, when you say "nothing happens", I guess that means your program is working.

Comment: whenever we use **Input Stream Reader** and **Buffered Reader**, we should put them in **try/catch**? (I see lots of codes which uses these way to get data from user, and all of them, put it in **try/catch** block. So, I think using **Scanner** for getting data from user, is much more easier, right?)